# Match datetime property value in response value array list using groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy, soapui

I am trying to match if my datetime variable present in array of multiple dates but error popup displayed.

Error :

```
assert responseStartDateTime.contains(requestStartDateTime) | | | | false 2018-01-16T04:30:00 [2018-01-16T04:30:00, 2018-01-16T06:00:00]
```

Groovy code :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

//request local time
def StartDateTime = context.expand('${#Project#StartDateTime}')
log.info 'Request StartTime : ' + StartDateTime
def EndDateTime = context.expand('${#Project#EndDateTime}')
log.info 'Request EndTime : ' + EndDateTime

//Remove Z from the request time
def outputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
start =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(StartDateTime)
end = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(EndDateTime)
def requestStartDateTime = "${start.format(outputDateFormat)}"
log.info 'Request StartTime : ' + requestStartDateTime
def requestEndDateTime = "${end.format(outputDateFormat)}"
log.info 'Request EndTime : ' + requestEndDateTime

def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

//Store response local time result to variable
def responseStartDateTime = jsonSlurper.MeetingItems.TimeFrom
log.info 'Response StartTime : ' + responseStartDateTime
def responseEndDateTime = jsonSlurper.MeetingItems.TimeTo
log.info 'Response EndTime : ' + responseEndDateTime

//Assert request local time with response local time
assert responseStartDateTime.contains(requestStartDateTime)
assert responseEndDateTime.contains(requestEndDateTime)
```

Property values :

```
StartDateTime - 2018-01-16T04:30:00.000Z
EndDateTime - 2018-01-16T04:45:00.000Z
```

Comment: Try changing `def requestStartDateTime = "${start.format(outputDateFormat)}"` to `def requestStartDateTime = start.format(outputDateFormat)`

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates This works. What is the difference between them.

Comment: @rAJ, The result of yours is `GString` and what is suggested is direct assignment and results `String`.